# Click() function in Selenium doesn't always work

Tags: python

I'm having some problems with the click function, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I don't think the problem is in the xpath, since one out three tries it clicks, nor in the time because I used a *WebDriverWait* for each element. I tried a bunch of alternatives but they all gave me the same problem or didn't work at all: I tried with `submit()`, `send_keys()`, `ActionChains`, click through `JavaScript` and some others.
Ultimately I wanted to try with a loop where the click is iterated until the next button is visible, but also this solution isn't working consistently, maybe there are some errors in the code:

```
             Flag = False
             while not Flag:
                 try:
                     element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                         EC.presence_of_element_located(
                             (By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[7]/div/div[3]/div/form/div/div[10]/div/label/span'))
                     )
                     element.click()
                     time.sleep(1)
                 except:
                     AddToButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                         EC.presence_of_element_located(
                             (By.XPATH,
                              "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/x-wrapper-re-1-6/div/div[2]/button"))
                     )
                     AddToButton.click()
                     Flag = True
```

Also, everytime I run the code I get this error:
`File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\TryProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until     raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)`

Comment: Is the element you are trying to click rendered on the page before you click it? One way I debug Selenium issues is to put like a 1 minute pause between suspicious commands to see what Selenium sees. I know I had such problems when clicking on a button that opened a Bootstrap modal. It took like 0.8 seconds for the modal to appear, so I had to wait that long before clicking anything on it. Perhaps you can specify what the exact error message is.

Comment: I tried with long implicit wait too but they don't make any difference and since it's a dropdown menu I thought that the webdriverwait would solve the timing issue. I don't get any error when the button isn't clicked, the only error I get is `File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\TryProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)` but it's shown both when the script works both when it doesn't

Comment: Put that error message in your question. It does appear to be helpful. It could also be that your xpath is wrong. I always try to avoid those things because they're so hard to debug.. Use an ID or class name.

Comment: I know the xpath is not ideal but it was the only one that worked since the div names and the class names were the same for every item and I wanted to select a particular one.

Comment: @Bobort you were right, the problem was in the xpath, I simplified it and now it's always working